# how to wait for a few seconds before starting a function

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to reload a gun. When R pressed. I want it to wait 3 seconds before loading the gun. Is there a simple way to do this?

example:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
        {
            //wait(4 seconds)

                           // start reloading
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for 3 seconds in ActionScript 2 or 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052221/how-to-wait-for-3-seconds-in-actionscript-2-or-3)

Comment: It's different. The other topic is about waiting just 3 seconds. Crook wants to wait 4 :/

Comment: yes indeed, my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reloadTimer = new Timer(4000,1); //add a 4 second timer
reloadTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,reload);

function handleKeyPress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
    {
        reloadTimer.reset() //in case it was still going (otherwise add check for if already reloading)
        reloadTimer.start();
    }
}
```

When the key is pressed, it will start the 4 second timer. At the end of the 4 seconds, the reload function will execute. You should put your code for reloading in there.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use setTimeout:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
{
    setTimeout( reload, 3000 );
}

...

function reload():void
{
    // do reload
}
```

It internally uses the Timer/TimerEvent classes. Neither methods are all that accurate and you should probably be using a main game timer that you calculate on each frame.